# Print 1 , 2 , 3 consecutively by 3 threads using single runnable does not work

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to print 1 by Thread-1,
               2 by Thread-2,
               3 by Thread-3
like 123123123 and so on

this i want to achieve using only one runnable object shared by multiple threads 
baiscally the way i have tried is 
have used one atomicInteger as signalling to indicate which should print
and used wait and notify to transfer the control between the threads and have
used threadName check to allow the specific thread to print

I have tried this like below and its not working can someone please help me in this.

```
/** Main class which creates 3 threads using one runnable and 
    starts the 3 threads */ 
package PrintOneTwoThree;
public class MainClass
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    //one runnable is created and shared by 3 threads
    final PrintNumbersConsecutively printRunnable = new 
                               PrintNumbersConsecutively();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(printRunnable, "Thread1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(printRunnable,"Thread2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(printRunnable,"Thread3");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
 }
}

/** Each of the three threads are made to print 1 ,2 and 3 */
package PrintOneTwoThree;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class PrintNumbersConsecutively implements Runnable
{
  private Object monitor = new Object();
  AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(1);

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Started");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    printNumbers();
}

// method to print the numbers using 3 different threads 1 ,2 and 3
public void printNumbers()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (monitor) 
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"held 
                               the lock of monitor");
                System.out.println("printVal is"+ atomicInt);

                 //Thread1 should print 1
                if(atomicInt.get() == 1 && 
                        Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1"))
                {
                    //prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 2
                    System.out.println(1);
                    atomicInt.set(2);
                    monitor.notifyAll();

              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Releasing 
              the lock of monitor");
                    monitor.wait();
                }

                //Thread 2 should print 2
                if(atomicInt.get() == 2 && 
                     Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread2"))
                {
                    //prints 2 and next awakes third thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 3
                    System.out.println(2);
                    atomicInt.set(3);
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                    monitor.wait();
                }

                //Thread 3 should print 3
                if(atomicInt.get() == 3 && 
                   Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread3"))
                {
                    //prints 3 and next awakes first thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 1
                    System.out.println(3);
                    atomicInt.set(1);
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        //catches the interrupted excpeiton
    }
}
}
```

output is

```
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
printVal is1
Thread2held the lock of monitor
```

Comment: one more doubt in this case synchronized(this) does not work, and it throws IllegalStateMontiorException at different lines in application. can you please me know why , basically what is the difference between synchronized(sameObject i.e this) and synchronized(different object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made following changes in the code

- Add wait
- Change If conditions

  ```
  public class Practice {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      //one runnable is created and shared by 3 threads
      final PrintNumbersConsecutively printRunnable = new
      PrintNumbersConsecutively();
      Thread t1 = new Thread(printRunnable, "Thread1");
      Thread t2 = new Thread(printRunnable,"Thread2");
      Thread t3 = new Thread(printRunnable,"Thread3");

      t1.start();
      t2.start();
      t3.start();
   }
  }

   /** Each of the three threads are made to print 1 ,2 and 3 */

  class PrintNumbersConsecutively implements Runnable
  {
  private Object monitor = new Object();
  AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(1);

  static boolean one = true;
  static boolean two = false;
  static boolean three = false;

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Started");
      printNumbers();
  }

  // method to print the numbers using 3 different threads 1 ,2 and 3
  public void printNumbers()
  {
      try
      {
          int i =0;
          while(i < 30)
          {
              synchronized (monitor)
              {
                  /*System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" held the lock of monitor");
                  System.out.println("printVal is"+ atomicInt);*/
                  //Thread1 should print 1
                  if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1")) {
                      if (atomicInt.get() == 1) {
                          //prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                          // atomic int to 2
                          System.out.print(1 + " ");
                          atomicInt.set(2);
                          monitor.notifyAll();
                         // System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                      } else {
                          monitor.wait();
                      }
                  }

                  if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread2")) {
                      if (atomicInt.get() == 2) {
                          //prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                          // atomic int to 2
                          System.out.print(2 + " ");
                          atomicInt.set(3);
                          monitor.notifyAll();
                        //  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                      } else {
                          monitor.wait();
                      }
                  }

                  if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread3")) {
                      if (atomicInt.get() == 3) {
                          //prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                          // atomic int to 2
                          System.out.print(3 + " ");
                          atomicInt.set(1);
                          monitor.notifyAll();
                          //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                      } else {
                          monitor.wait();
                      }
                  }
              }
              i++;
          }

      }
      catch(InterruptedException e)
      {
          //catches the interrupted excpeiton
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Output :

```
Thread3Started
Thread1Started
Thread2Started
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
```

Comment: Appreciate your sincere efforts in the answer , very helpfull, thank u

Comment: No worries, Happy coding :)

Comment: one more doubt in this case synchronized(this) does not work, and it throws IllegalStateMontiorException at different lines in application. can you please me know why , basically what is the difference between synchronized(sameObject i.e this) and synchronized(different object i.e monitor)

Answer (score 3):

The same can be achieved using the following code. Here we are not using any Atomic classes, but instead a simple monitor object `obj` and a counter variable `count`.

```
class T3 {

public Object obj = new Object();
private int MAX = 100;
int count = 1, value = -1;

public void process1() {
    while (true) {
        if (count > MAX) break;
        synchronized (obj) {
            if (value == -1) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count++);
                value = 0;
                obj.notifyAll();
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void process2() {
    while (true) {
        if (count > MAX) break;
        synchronized (obj) {
            if (value == 0) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count++);
                value = 1;
                obj.notifyAll();
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void process3() {
    while (true) {
        if (count > MAX) break;
        synchronized (obj) {
            if (value == 1) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count++);
                value = -1;
                obj.notifyAll();
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your sincere efforts in the answer , very helpfull, thank u

Comment: one more doubt in this case synchronized(this) does not work, and it throws IllegalStateMontiorException at different lines in application. can you please me know why , basically what is the difference between synchronized(sameObject i.e this) and synchronized(different object i.e monitor

Comment: You get that exception when you dont have a lock on the object and you try to perform `obj.wait()`, `obj.notify()` or `obj.notifyAll()`

Answer (score 1):

A thread should wait if it's not its turn.

```
public void printNumbers()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (monitor) 
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"held the lock of monitor");
                System.out.println("printVal is"+ atomicInt);

                 //Thread1 should print 1
                if(atomicInt.get() == 1 && 
                        Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1"))
                {
                    //prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 2
                    System.out.println(1);
                    atomicInt.set(2);
                    monitor.notifyAll();

              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Releasing the lock of monitor");
                }

                //Thread 2 should print 2
                if(atomicInt.get() == 2 && 
                     Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread2"))
                {
                    //prints 2 and next awakes third thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 3
                    System.out.println(2);
                    atomicInt.set(3);
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                }

                //Thread 3 should print 3
                if(atomicInt.get() == 3 && 
                   Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread3"))
                {
                    //prints 3 and next awakes first thread by setting
                    // atomic int to 1
                    System.out.println(3);
                    atomicInt.set(1);
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                }
                monitor.wait();
            }
        }

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        //catches the interrupted excpeiton
    }
}
```

Comment: one more doubt in this case synchronized(this) does not work, and it throws IllegalStateMontiorException at different lines in application. can you please me know why , basically what is the difference between synchronized(sameObject i.e this) and synchronized(different object i.e monitor

Comment: @sachinsarangamath there is no difference: the monitor is the object used in `synchronized(x)`. You get an `illegalStateMonitorException` when you do a `obj.wait()` or a `obj.notify()` outside of a synchronized(obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

the tiny change of your code is moving all **monitor.wait()** from **if {}** section,

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    if() {
      ....
    }
    if() {
      ....
    }
    if() {
      ....
    }
    monitor.wait()
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your sincere efforts in the answer , very helpfull, thank u

Comment: one more doubt in this case synchronized(this) does not work, and it throws IllegalStateMontiorException at different lines in application. can you please me know why , basically what is the difference between synchronized(sameObject i.e this) and synchronized(different object i.e monitor

Comment: please remove all **monitor** prefix in your code, for example **monitor.notifyAll() -> notifyAll(), monitor.wait() -> wait()**

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and tested output,I was getting output the way you printed so I just shuffled print message because it was not printed sophisticated way so again I tested output it is printing the way you want.I think there is not any problem in the code.Please try this code.

```
 public class MainClass {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            // one runnable is created and shared by 3 threads
            final PrintNumbersConsecutively printRunnable = new PrintNumbersConsecutively();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(printRunnable, "Thread1");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(printRunnable, "Thread2");
            Thread t3 = new Thread(printRunnable, "Thread3");

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();
        }
    }

    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

    public class PrintNumbersConsecutively implements Runnable {
        private Object  monitor     = new Object();
        AtomicInteger   atomicInt   = new AtomicInteger(1);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Started");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            printNumbers();
        }

        // method to print the numbers using 3 different threads 1 ,2 and 3
        public void printNumbers() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (monitor) {

                        // Thread1 should print 1
                        if (atomicInt.get() == 1 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1")) {
                            // prints 1 and next awakes second thread by setting
                            // atomic int to 2
                            atomicInt.set(2);
                            System.out.println(1);
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                            monitor.notifyAll();

                            monitor.wait();
                        }

                        // Thread 2 should print 2
                        if (atomicInt.get() == 2 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread2")) {
                            // prints 2 and next awakes third thread by setting
                            // atomic int to 3
                            atomicInt.set(3);
                            System.out.println(2);
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                            monitor.notifyAll();
                            monitor.wait();
                        }

                        // Thread 3 should print 3
                        if (atomicInt.get() == 3 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread3")) {
                            // prints 3 and next awakes first thread by setting
                            // atomic int to 1
                            atomicInt.set(1);
                            System.out.println(3);
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Releasing the lock of monitor");
                            monitor.notifyAll();
                            monitor.wait();
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // catches the interrupted excpeiton
            }
        }
    }


Output :

Thread1Started
Thread2Started
Thread3Started
1
Thread1Releasing the lock of monitor
2
Thread2Releasing the lock of monitor
3
Thread3Releasing the lock of monitor
1
Thread1Releasing the lock of monitor
2
Thread2Releasing the lock of monitor
3
Thread3Releasing the lock of monitor
1
Thread1Releasing the lock of monitor
2
Thread2Releasing the lock of monitor
3
Thread3Releasing the lock of monitor
```